# Access UPDATE to Today's Date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

While I'm running below Query from access VBA, it's updating the date to 12/30/1899. Please help me.

```
DQRY = "Update " & tb & " Set ImportDate =  " & Format(Now, "MM/DD/YYYY") & ";"
db.Execute DQRY
```

while DORY equivalents to

> "Update 600_London_Name Set ImportDate =  09/26/2017;"

Yet the result I get in the table is 12/30/1899. Below is my Table structure.

[image: Table Description]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the built-in `date()` function in MS Access:

```
DQRY = "Update " & tb & " Set ImportDate =  date() "
```

Comment: It's still returning 12/30/1899. However when I remove the format type of field column from "Short Date" to blank, it updates 12:00:15 AM instead.

Comment: Wait.. it worked... I was trying `DQRY = "Update " & tb & " Set ImportDate =  " & Date & ";"` instead of `DQRY = "Update " & tb & " Set ImportDate =  Date();"`